# Magento 2 - change text of PDF invoice for purchase order

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, invoice, pdf, purchase-order

How can I change the text of **"purchase order"** section in the **PDF invoice** which **Magento** creates?

When the payment method is "purchase order" (instead of credit card or paypal), Magento prints the purchase order number in the PDF invoice. I would like to add specific **payment instructions** to the PDF when order is done with the "purchase order" method.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

found it:

vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/adminhtml/templates/info/pdf/purchaseorder.phtml

Magento 2.2.5